# mysql subselect alternative

Tags: sql, mysql, optimization

Lets say I am analyzing how high school sports records affect school attendance.

So I have a table in which each row corresponds to a high school basketball game. Each game has an away team id and a home team id (FK to another "team table") and a home score and an away score and a date.  I am writing a query that matches attendance with this seasons basketball games.

My sample output will be (`#_students_missed_class`, `day_of_game`, `home_team`, `away_team`, `home_team_wins_this_season`, `away_team_wins_this_season`)

I now want to add how each team did the previous season to my analysis.  Well, I have their previous season stored in the game table but i should be able to accomplish that with a subselect.

So in my main select statement I add the subselect:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM game_table
WHERE game_table.date
BETWEEN 'start of previous season' AND 'end of previous season'
AND (
  (game_table.home_team = team_table.id
    AND game_table.home_score > game_table.away_score)
  OR (game_table.away_team = team_table.id
    AND game_table.away_score > game_table.home_score))
```

In this case team-table.id refers to the id of the home_team so I now have all their wins calculated from the previous year.

This method of calculation is neither time nor resource intensive.  The Explain SQL shows that I have ALL in the Type field and I am not using a Key and the query times out.  I'm not sure how I can accomplish a more efficient query with a subselect.  It seems proposterously inefficient to have to write 4 of these queries (for home wins, home losses, away wins, away losses).

I am sure this could be more lucid.  I'll absolutely add color tomorrow if anyone has questions

Comment: thanks, I never knew that was the proper etiquette.  I went back and did that / will do it in the future as well

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, this is another case of "trying to get my rdbms to do everything for me".  You have to accept that you can't optimise your database for some scenarios / queries, and no matter how many indexes you add, things like sub-queries are going to slow down the larger parent query.

You above example is a clear case of this: the data you are showing from the sub-query (the performance of a team in the previous season) is static data - it's historical and can't / won't change.  You should query for this data separately, hold it in-memory in your application, and manually add it to the results of you main query as you loop over it.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. For the sake of athis example  say I had to generate the results in SQL.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Your best option in MySQL would be to have a view that you can join to as many times as you need.

If MySQL supported CTEs then you could do it all in a single statement...

```
with prior_season as (
  select ...
)
  select
     ...
  join prior_season as hone_wins on ...
  join prior_season as home_losses on ...
  ... etc
```

If this is something you're going to want to do a lot, it might be a decent argument for switching to a different RDBMS.  Postgres supports them now, and pretty much all of the major commercial vendor's free versions do as well.